# Numbers to words along with decimal value count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert numbers to text but when I'm trying to convert number along with decimal value that is not showing up but when only number is entered with out decimal value that works perfect and the decimal value is MAX 2 digits am not sure how too do that.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shaikasifpasha3/5tt7d3e6/3/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Number OR Amount" onkeyup="word.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" />
<div id="word"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function convertNumberToWords(amount) {
    var words = new Array();
    words[0] = '';
    words[1] = 'One';
    words[2] = 'Two';
    words[3] = 'Three';
    words[4] = 'Four';
    words[5] = 'Five';
    words[6] = 'Six';
    words[7] = 'Seven';
    words[8] = 'Eight';
    words[9] = 'Nine';
    words[10] = 'Ten';
    words[11] = 'Eleven';
    words[12] = 'Twelve';
    words[13] = 'Thirteen';
    words[14] = 'Fourteen';
    words[15] = 'Fifteen';
    words[16] = 'Sixteen';
    words[17] = 'Seventeen';
    words[18] = 'Eighteen';
    words[19] = 'Nineteen';
    words[20] = 'Twenty';
    words[30] = 'Thirty';
    words[40] = 'Forty';
    words[50] = 'Fifty';
    words[60] = 'Sixty';
    words[70] = 'Seventy';
    words[80] = 'Eighty';
    words[90] = 'Ninety';
    amount = amount.toString();
    var atemp = amount.split(".");
    var number = atemp[0].split(",").join("");
    var n_length = number.length;
    var words_string = "";
    if (n_length <= 9) {
        var n_array = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var received_n_array = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < n_length; i++) {
            received_n_array[i] = number.substr(i, 1);
        }
        for (var i = 9 - n_length, j = 0; i < 9; i++, j++) {
            n_array[i] = received_n_array[j];
        }
        for (var i = 0, j = 1; i < 9; i++, j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
                if (n_array[i] == 1) {
                    n_array[j] = 10 + parseInt(n_array[j]);
                    n_array[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        value = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
                value = n_array[i] * 10;
            } else {
                value = n_array[i];
            }
            if (value != 0) {
                words_string += words[value] + " ";
            }
            if ((i == 1 && value != 0) || (i == 0 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Crores ";
            }
            if ((i == 3 && value != 0) || (i == 2 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Lakhs ";
            }
            if ((i == 5 && value != 0) || (i == 4 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Thousand ";
            }
            if (i == 6 && value != 0 && (n_array[i + 1] != 0 && n_array[i + 2] != 0)) {
                words_string += "Hundred and ";
            } else if (i == 6 && value != 0) {
                words_string += "Hundred ";
            }
        }
        words_string = words_string.split("  ").join(" ");
    }
    return words_string;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the same function for getting the whole and the decimal part

```
function withDecimal(n) {
    var nums = n.toString().split('.')
    var whole = convertNumberToWords(nums[0])
    if (nums.length == 2) {
        var fraction = convertNumberToWords(nums[1])
        return whole + 'and ' + fraction;
    } else {
        return whole;
    }
}

console.log(withDecimal(51.32)) //Fifty One and Thirty Two
console.log(withDecimal(29.0))  //Twenty Nine
```

Comment: this is perfect wat if there is zero number the and still shows

Comment: Sure that would be better

Comment: @Shaik I've updated answer, or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: instead of "return whole + 'and ' + fraction;" it should be "let ret = whole + ' and ' + fraction; return ret"

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution for your problem.

```
var th = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion'];

var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
var tw = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];
function toWords(s) {
    s = s.toString();
    s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
    if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number';
    var x = s.indexOf('.');
    if (x == -1) x = s.length;
    if (x > 15) return 'too big';
    var n = s.split('');
    var str = '';
    var sk = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
            if (n[i] == '1') {
                str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
                i++;
                sk = 1;
            } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
                sk = 1;
            }
        } else if (n[i] != 0) {
            str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
            sk = 1;
        }
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
            if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
            sk = 0;
        }
    }
    if (x != s.length) {
        var y = s.length;
        str += 'point ';
        for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
    }
    return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but can you share me the demo iam not able to make out

Answer (score 0):

I used Mr.isvforall's idea added little for my application of eCheck pritning.

```
function withDecimal(n) {
    var nums = n.toString().split('.')
    var whole = convertNumberToWords(nums[0])
    if (nums.length == 2) {
        var fraction = convertNumberToWords(nums[1])
      //  return whole + 'and ' + fraction;
        return whole + 'and ' +  nums[1] + "/100";
    } else {
        return whole;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I found the solution for this...

```js
function convertToIndianWords(amount) {
    const units = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
    const teens = ['eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
    const tens = ['', 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];
    const scales = ['', 'thousand', 'lakh', 'crore'];

    function convertToWordsLessThanThousand(n) {
        if (n < 10) {
            return units[n];
        } else if (n < 20) {
            return teens[n - 11];
        } else if (n < 100) {
            return tens[Math.floor(n / 10)] + (n % 10 !== 0 ? ' ' + units[n % 10] : '');
        } else {
            return units[Math.floor(n / 100)] + ' hundred' + (n % 100 !== 0 ? ' and ' + convertToWordsLessThanThousand(n % 100) : '');
        }
    }

    function convertAmountToWords(amount) {
        let wholePart = Math.floor(amount);
        const decimalPart = Math.round((amount - wholePart) * 100); // considering up to two decimal places

        const wholeWords = convertToWordsLessThanThousand(wholePart);
        const decimalWords = decimalPart > 0 ? 'and ' + convertToWordsLessThanThousand(decimalPart) + ' paise' : '';

        if (wholeWords === 'zero') {
            return 'zero rupees only';
        }

        const words = [];
        let scaleIndex = 0;

        while (wholePart > 0) {
            const chunk = wholePart % 1000;
            if (chunk !== 0) {
                words.unshift(convertToWordsLessThanThousand(chunk) + ' ' + scales[scaleIndex]);
            }
            wholePart = Math.floor(wholePart / 1000);
            scaleIndex++;
        }

        return words.join(' ') + ' rupees ' + decimalWords +' only';
    }

    return convertAmountToWords(amount);
}

// Example usage:
const amount = 5994.40;
const amountInWords = convertToIndianWords(amount);

console.log(amountInWords);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!